# How can I kill all processes in a process group when there is any signal or interrrupt to any of processes in the group?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing, signals

I have two processes A and B (should be scalable). A and B can have sub-processes (which includes execl'd processes as well).
If a signal is delevered to any of the subprocesses, the program should terminate gracefully terminating all the sub-processes of A and B including A and B itself.

The challenge here is that there should not be any defunct processes and since there could be execl'd process, the address space gets replaced.

I created a child process first and assigned pid of child process to the the pgid while parent just waits. Also, I created the processes A and B inside this child process, such that I could terminate all the processes with pgrp.

But as I mentioned, when I issue "kill pid of execld process", it created defunct process, with all other processes running.

Also, my requirement is such that I cant go for multi-threading (at least for the intended work)

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Keep a signal handler. In the handler, get the group ID using `os.getgid()`, then delete all processes in that group using `os.kill`. To see how to get all processes in a given group, check [this](https://superuser.com/a/763988) out. You can use `subprocess.Popen` to execute that command via shell and get the results in your script.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. When I implemented, I am in loop getting the signal continuously. May be I need to remove the current process pid in process group. But cant think of how to do it?

Comment: What kind of signal are you looking for? I believe python-2.7 does not handle keyboard interrupt properly.

Comment: I am actually not sure. But for testing, I am just issuing "kill -9 subprocess-pid". May be if I could get list of pid under specific process group, so that I can ignore current pid.

Comment: Don't mean to disappoint but `kill -9` cannot be caught or handled.

Comment: Tried with "kill pid" as well. Same results.

Comment: Try a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl+C)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146323/discussion-between-harsha-and-coldspeed).